# how do I override awt paint() method correctly

Tags: java, awt, paint, repaint

I have a subclass from `java.awt.Window`. In this subclass I want to override the `public void paint(Graphics g)` function to draw my own things on it.

The problem is that I dont know how to invoke the repaint correctly. Everything is implemented and I am sure that it works, because if I open a `FileChooser` and close it the `java.awt.Window` repaints and the correct things are shown on it.

But if I call the `repaint()` method of the object by myself it does not get repainted.

Do you have any idea how I invoke the repaint correctly?

```
public class MyWindow extends java.awt.Window {
    public MyWindows(Window owner) {
        super(owner);
    }
    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.fillRect(50,50,50,50);
    }
}

MyWindow window = new MyWindow(owner);
window.repaint(); //this call the paint method but dont show drawn things
```

Comment: @VinceEmigh thanks for that correction

Comment: You mention in another comment that you're using vlcj, well in the vlcj test sources there are examples of exactly what you're trying to do. https://github.com/caprica/vlcj/blob/master/src/test/java/uk/co/caprica/vlcj/test/overlay

Answer (score 1):

I suggest reading the [custom painting tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) provided by Oracle.

First, you should be using a frame, not a window. Use `JFrame`, which is what Swing provides for creating frames. Swing is built ontop of AWT, and is pefered for modern development.

Rather than overriding `paint(Graphics)` of the frame (painting on the frame), you should create a new panel and override it's paint method. It's also recommended to override `paintComponent` rather than `paint`:

```
class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);

        //paint
    }
}
```

You can then add this panel to your frame:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(() -> {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel = new MyPanel();
        panel.setSize(...);
        frame.add(panel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. I am using VLCj in my application and the `EmbeddedMediaPlayer` class supports an Window accessor to place Overlays above the video. That is the reason why I have to use java.awt.Window ;). I you have any idea to work around, I would appreciate it.

Comment: If it accepts `Window`, it'll accept `JFrame` since it extends `Window` (a `JFrame` [is a](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Is-a) `Window`)

Comment: ok I will check that tomorrow. Am I right when I think that I can also override paint() there?